# Empty model, empty table

Tags: java, jtable

I have a JTable as a viewer of a model that I have created. I can insert and remove columns and rows from this model. The problem is that when my model reaches size 0, i.e., no data in the model, the table continuouing showing the header for the last two columns.

All the best,
Leandro Lima

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question - JTable will always show the table header irrespective of whether it contains any visible rows (and providing you have embedded it within a JScrollPane).  What is the desired behaviour here?

Comment: Hi Adam, 
My header is also dynamic. So, when I remove a column, header goes out too. The problem is the bad behavior when I do not have any column. If the table is open without columns it works well, nothing is showed on screen, but if I remove my columns it doesn't work well, the last two headers don't disapear.

Comment: When you say "remove a column" how are you doing this?  Are you setting its width to zero or actually modifiying the TableModel (in which case you need to fire a table structure changed event?).  Can you please post some code snippets?

Comment: Remove the column is remove from the model and fire a table struture changed. Sorry, the code is from my job and I don't have permision to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved. I wasn't firing data struct changed at the last remove action.